# How does Hangover stack?

Tags: hades

[Hangover](https://hades.gamepedia.com/Status_effects#Status_Curses) is essentially Hades version of poison, and is the main mechanic for the god [Dionysus](https://hades.gamepedia.com/Dionysus). Different sources of Hangover will inflict differing  amounts of damage-per-tick (i.e. hangover inflicted by your special is more damaging than hangover inflicted by your dash), and it can stack up to 5 times. The part I'm unclear on, since the game doesn't explain it, is how hangover effects stack when that damage is coming from multiple sources.

I can think of a few different ways it could work, with the two most likely candidates being that either the *oldest* stack is overwritten, or the *lowest damage* stack is overridden. If it's the former, then combining multiple sources of hangover can actually be really bad, since using anything but your highest damage Hangover attack would actually be lowering your Hangover damage-per-tick.

This would be easy to test if you actually could actually use boons against [Skelly](https://hades.gamepedia.com/Skelly), but you can't, so the only option is testing in combat. Considering how fast past the game is, that's a task easier said than done.

How do different sources of  Hangover stack?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Once the maximum number of stacks has been reached, any new stacks will **override the oldest stack.** This means you'll rarely want more than one source of Hangover, since your weaker hangover stacks will override your stronger ones.

I was able to confirm this by experimenting against against multiple enemies in Elysium. I wasn't able to confirm it earlier since the enemies pre-Elysium were just too squishy (aka they die way too quickly).